# If a method calls another method, is it a unit test or integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

Im a beginner in tdd concept, so my question is, if I have a method that calls another method, as simple as it may sound, it is a unit test or a integration test? If its a Integration Test, it is just because my method calls another method and there have a "integration" between methods?

Comment: I think your question is ill-formed. What methods are you talking about? Do they all belong to the code being tested, to the test, to both? But whichever way it is, it does not say anything about the kind of test it is and that's the key here. Is this a test that tests things in isolation from others? Is this a test that tests multiple things, how they work with one another? IOW, are you testing the wheel and the engine separately or attached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I have a method that calls another method, as simple as it may sound, it is a unit test or a integration test?

Sadly, that's going to depend on whose definition of "unit test" and "integration test" you are using.  Twenty years ago, when those definitions were driven by experts in the domain of software testing, the question would be easier to answer.

But TDD happened; and Kent Beck wasn't particularly disciplined about his definitions, and a bunch of new ideas started to bubble in.

Even within the context of TDD, there are subtle disagreements about what "unit test" means.  For instance, one important idea is that tests should not be sensitive to the order in which they are run; each individual test contained all the setup and teardown necessary to correctly measure the system.  Another was that two tests, running at the same time within the same process, should not interfere with each other; so no shared mutable state..

The common theme here is that the *test* is constrained; "unit test" would describe tests that have a specific set of properties.

A different idea came about from the observation that large tests are, without very careful design, brittle over the lifetime of a project.  If the observable behavior of the *test subject* depends in turn on many different decisions which are likely to change, then brittle tests are a common result.

So a different sort of constraint broke out, suggesting that test subjects should be small - a "unit test" is one in which the behavior of the test subject depends on only a modest number of decisions that might potentially change.

Adding even more confusion to the mix, the rituals that Beck and others had used with some success were marketed at various times as "Test First Development", "Test Driven Development", "Test Driven Design" -- which confused the motivation.  Is the purpose `test`, or is the purpose `design`?

As best I can tell, everybody agrees that a method that doesn't delegate any of its work is a good subject for a unit test.

Furthermore, everybody agrees that a method that delegates its work to stable collaborators (the standard library, for example) is a good subject for a unit test.

But disagreement begins when we replace the design that uses no collaborators with a design that uses unstable collaborators (delegating work to other methods, especially if they are in different "classes").

Is it still a unit test if we change the design to share the work among unstable parts?  I'm fairly sure that Beck would say yes, as would Freeman and Pryce.  I'm less sure about @JBrains; see [Integrated Tests are a Scam](https://vimeo.com/80533536).  Some have done their own experiments and come to a position that they find works for them; others have their interpretation of the
"best practices" described by their favored experts.

In short: it's a mess.

The best answer I can offer is that, instead of worrying about the *labels* we use for different flavors of tests, concentrate on the interesting sets of *properties*, the constraints you need to ensure the tests have those properties, and aligning those properties with their use.

For example, if you are going to be running tests many times during a development session, as a mechanism for catching mistakes early, then you probably want those tests to be fast, and independent of what's happening in environments outside your own.  To get those properties, you probably need to avoid network traffic in your tests, and possibly even I/O -- doing "everything" in memory is a lot faster (and leaves you exposed to certain risks that you'll need to manage in other ways).

Comment: A nice answer, and thanks for leaving some space to put up another answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is really helpful, but let's add this thought:

> if I have a method that calls another method

It starts right there. If that *other* method that gets called lives inside your "unit under test", then I would consider it a unit test.

If that method sits in "another" unit, (which is not "under test", but a "dependency"), then it depends: if you mock/stub that other unit, I think you are still running a unit test. But one could even claim: when that other unit can just be called directly, without stubbing, you might still run a unit test on that initial piece.

In other words, you look at the purpose, and the "definition" of what "unit" wraps around: when I write a suite of tests that all work the public methods of one Java class, then most likely, these are unit tests. Maybe I have to stub dependencies, maybe I did a great design and dependant units can be used without workarounds.

The "next" level isn't integration testing though. It is "function" testing. Instead of looking at "class X does this or that", you ask "does feature Y work", without worrying if you need only class X for that, or 5 other classes. You care about a larger (end to end) functionality, not about an individual "unit" of code organization.

The "next" level, that would be integration testing. In my book, those are about making sure that a whole set of features/functions come together, and each one is doing what it should do, with a certain focus on aspects that were stubbed/mocked/ignored on the lower unit/function test side of things.

Answer (score 2):

I would go further and will try to forget about "unit", "integration", "behaviour" or "acceptance" tests, instead divide all test in two groups

- Fast tests
- Slow tests

  - when accessing external resources (File System, Database, Web services etc.)
  - very complicated test case to configure

By mocking external resources or very complicated dependencies you can move some test cases in the "Fast" category and provide quicker feedback to the developer.

I would try to mock as less as possible, as far as tests executes quick enough to run them after every change in the code.

Then "unit" will become a unit of behaviour, which will test behaviour of application and keeping application as a "black box" as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Integration Testing mean testing different modules after integrating
Unit Testing mean Testing module as a complete unit.
In my view We called it both unit as well as integration testing